# The corresponding ctypes type of a numpy.dtype?

Tags: numpy, ctypes

If I have a numpy ndarray with a certain `dtype`, how do I know what is the corresponding ctypes type?

For example, if I have a ndarray, I can do the following to convert it to a shared array:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import ctypes
x_np = np.random.rand(10, 10)
x_mp = mp.Array(ctypes.c_double, x_np)
```

However, I have to specify `c_double` here. It works if I don't specify the exact same type, but I would like to keep the type the same. How should I find out the ctypes type of the ndarray `x_np` automatically, at least for some common elementary data types?

Comment: Since the multiprocessing module makes a copy of the array, you may want to instead allocate the ctypes array using multiprocessing and then access it from another process (without copying) using numpy, e.g. main process: `x_mp = mp.Array('d', 100);` child process: `x_np = np.reshape(np.ctypeslib.as_array(x_mp.get_obj()), (10, 10));` `x_np[:] = np.random.rand(10, 10)`.

Comment: For the shared array all you really need is a byte array, assuming it's big enough, which you then cast appropriately using `np.frombuffer` and `np.reshape`. This way the data is all determined by your numpy code, while the multiprocessing array is just providing the backing store of shared memory.

Comment: Thank you! Yes either way works for me but what I have from my user is a numpy array. So if I follow your approach I still have to figure out what to put in the `'d'` part in your command given a numpy array. Do you have any idea? Curerntly I'm just using a customized dictionary to map from numpy.dtype.type to a ctypes type.

Comment: If you're OK with a private copy instead of sharing the original array, note that the first step is to flatten the array, e.g. `x_np = x_np.flatten()`, because your example above doesn't work. Then get `ct = np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes(x_np)` and descend through the `_type_` attribute until you get to a string, e.g. `while not isinstance(ct, str): ct = ct._type_`.

Answer (score 6):

This is now supported by [`numpy.ctypeslib.as_ctypes_type(dtype)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html#numpy.ctypeslib.as_ctypes_type):

```py
import numpy as np
x_np = np.random.rand(10, 10)
np.ctypeslib.as_ctypes_type(x_np.dtype)
```

Gives `ctypes.c_double`, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a way to do this that's [built into Numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.0/numpy/ctypeslib.py#L323):

```
x_np = np.random.rand(10, 10)
typecodes = np.ctypeslib._get_typecodes()
typecodes[x_np.__array_interface__['typestr']]
```

Output:

```
ctypes.c_double
```

The caveat is that the `np.ctypeslib._get_typecodes` function is marked as private (ie it's name starts with `_`). However, it doesn't seem like its implementation has changed in some time, so you can probably use it fairly reliably.

Alternatively, the implementation of `_get_typecodes` is pretty short, so you could just also copy the whole function over to your own code:

```
import ctypes
import numpy as np

def get_typecodes():
    ct = ctypes
    simple_types = [
        ct.c_byte, ct.c_short, ct.c_int, ct.c_long, ct.c_longlong,
        ct.c_ubyte, ct.c_ushort, ct.c_uint, ct.c_ulong, ct.c_ulonglong,
        ct.c_float, ct.c_double,
    ]

    return {np.dtype(ctype).str: ctype for ctype in simple_types}
```